# Unable to update linked MySQL table from SQL Server with MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.0

Tags: mysql, odbc, linked-server, openquery

I'm using a linked server on a SQL 2016 server to read and write data in different MySQL tables.

With MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.3 everything works fine, after updating the MySQL Connector/ODBC to latest version 8.0.26 due to security reasons updating the MySQL data causes an error! Selecting MySQL data still works fine, as well as inserting new data; updating and deleting MySQL data is not possible any longer.

In different threads I found hints for correct structure of MySQL tables as requirement to maintain the data via linked server. Tables must have a primary key column (with no auto increment) and at least one column with type timestamp must exist. So I created following simple test table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `test_odbc_3` (
      `TDBC_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `TDBC_DESC` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `TDBC_TSU` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`TDBC_ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_c
```

For maintenance of MySQL data I use the OPENQUERY syntax as follows:

Inserting a new row:

```
    INSERT OPENQUERY(TDBAMYSQLTEST, 'SELECT TDBC_ID, TDBC_DESC, TDBC_TSU FROM admin_db.test_odbc_3')
    VALUES (24,'row 4','2019-05-19 14:22:41)
```

works fine!

Selecting all rows:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM   OPENQUERY( TDBAMYSQLTEST, 'SELECT TDBC_ID, TDBC_DESC, TDBC_TSU FROM admin_db.test_odbc_3')
```

works fine – result is:
TDBC_ID   TDBC_DESC   TDBC_TSU

21   row 1   2009-04-17 14:11:41.0000000

22   row 2   2009-04-17 14:11:41.0000000

23   row 3   2009-04-17 14:11:41.0000000

24   row 4   2019-05-19 14:22:41.0000000

Trying to update a row in this table causes the following error:

```
    UPDATE OPENQUERY( TDBAMYSQLTEST, 'SELECT TDBC_ID, TDBC_DESC, TDBC_TSU FROM admin_db.test_odbc_3 WHERE TDBC_ID = 23')
    SET    TDBC_DESC = 'mydesc'
    WHERE  TDBC_ID = 23
     
    Msg 7343, Level 16, State 4, Line 10
    The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TDBAMYSQLTEST" could not UPDATE table "[MSDASQL]". Unknown provider error
```

Based on different threads I checked and set the configuration of environment as well.

MySQL Connector/ODBC configuration:
[ODBC driver information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnfre.png)

[ODBC connector configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtRUE.png)

Enabled Provider Options:

```
Dynamic parameter
Nested queries
Level zero only
Allow inprocess
Index as access path
```

Linked Server Properties set to True:

```
Data Access
RPC
RPC Out
```

Anybody has an idea about how to get running with update MySQL data again? Thnx in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `QPENQUERY` it's necessary to use `EXEC ... AT` syntax as follows:

- For selecting data:

  ```
  EXEC('SELECT * FROM  admin_db.test_odbc_3 WHERE TDBC_ID = 3') AT TDBAMYSQLTEST
  ```
- For updating data:

  ```
  EXEC('UPDATE admin_db.test_odbc_3 set TDBC_DESC = ''mynew_value'' WHERE TDBC_ID = 3') AT TDBAMYSQLTEST
  ```

Comment: This saved my bacon. Didn't realize this alternative way of doing it existed. Thank you!